# pip install matplotlib giving me an error i am using python3.9 windows 10

Tags: python

the error is

```
C:\>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
 ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1_l10b8m\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1_l10b8m\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g_9wqkff'
         cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1_l10b8m\matplotlib\
    Complete output (62 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.

    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.3.2]
          python: yes [3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC
                      v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]]
        platform: yes [win32]
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g_9wqkff\matplotlib.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g_9wqkff\matplotlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g_9wqkff\matplotlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing namespace_packages to C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g_9wqkff\matplotlib.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g_9wqkff\matplotlib.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g_9wqkff\matplotlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g_9wqkff\matplotlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1_l10b8m\matplotlib\setup.py", line 242, in <module>
        setup(  # Finally, pass this all along to distutils to do the heavy lifting.
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 298, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 305, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 536, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 572, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1_l10b8m\matplotlib\setup.py", line 88, in finalize_options
        self.distribution.ext_modules[:] = [
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1_l10b8m\matplotlib\setup.py", line 91, in <listcomp>
        for ext in package.get_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1_l10b8m\matplotlib\setupext.py", line 345, in get_extensions
        add_numpy_flags(ext)
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1_l10b8m\matplotlib\setupext.py", line 469, in add_numpy_flags
        import numpy as np
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
        _win_os_check()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
        raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
    RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('c:\\users\\dell\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: 
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with  `pip3` instead of `pip`

Comment: Still giving same error

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of python installed, they can clash, so you should the `pip` correspondent to your version, I.e. If you are installing matplotlib for python 3.8 then use `pip3.8`

Comment: I have only one version python 3.9  numpy, xlrd ,pandas are installed successfully only this one giving me error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem used `pip install matplotlib==3.3.1`